# SQL query to select records which is common for my first column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
    SEG_AIRLINE SEG_ORIGIN_CODE SEG_DESTINATION_CODE
    G9              ALA             DEL                         
    G9              ALA             DAC             
    G9              BKK             OOL                 
    SG              IXA             MAA         
    SG              BKK             OOL     
    SG              IXA             GAU         
    6E              IXA             AMD
    6E              BKK             OOL
    6E              IXA             DEL
    AK              BKK             MEL
    AK              BKK             OOL
    AK              BKK             PER
```

I have a table as like above. Now i want to select SEG_ORIGIN_CODE AND SEG_DESTINATION_CODE
which is common to all SEG_AIRLINE.

I want output like

```
    SEG_AIRLINE SEG_ORIGIN_CODE SEG_DESTINATION_CODE                                
    G9              BKK             OOL                         
    SG              BKK             OOL                 
    6E              BKK             OOL
    AK              BKK             OOL
```

I tried with this query

```
    SELECT SEG_AIRLINE ,SEG_ORIGIN_CODE ,SEG_DESTINATION_CODE 
    FROM T_N_SEGMENTS
    GROUP BY SEG_AIRLINE
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SEG_ORIGIN_CODE) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SEG_ORIGIN_CODE) FROM T_N_SEGMENTS)
```

Another solution I tried

```
    declare @airlineCount int
    select @airlineCount = count(distinct seg_airline) from T_N_SEGMENTS

    select seg_airline, seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code from T_N_SEGMENTS
    where
    (Select count(distinct seg_airline) from T_N_SEGMENTS s where s.seg_origin_code = T_N_SEGMENTS.seg_origin_code) = @airlineCount
    and
    (Select count(distinct seg_airline) from T_N_SEGMENTS s where s.seg_destination_code = T_N_SEGMENTS.seg_destination_code) = @airlineCount
```

but I dose not return any records

Comment: You want  X, but what have you attempted?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** based on your comments. This will give you rows with **the most common pair** of `seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code`

```
SELECT seg_airline, seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code
  FROM
(
  SELECT seg_airline, seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code, 
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) rank
    FROM
  (
    SELECT seg_airline, seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code) cnt
      FROM t_n_segments
  ) q
) p
 WHERE rank = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7abb8/1)** demo

---

You can do it this way

```
SELECT s.seg_airline, s.seg_origin_code, s.seg_destination_code
  FROM
(
  SELECT seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code 
    FROM t_n_segments
   GROUP BY seg_origin_code,seg_destination_code
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT seg_airline) = 
  (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT seg_airline)
      FROM t_n_segments
  )
) q JOIN t_n_segments s
    ON q.seg_origin_code = s.seg_origin_code
   AND q.seg_destination_code = s.seg_destination_code
```

or using windowing function

```
SELECT seg_airline, seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code
  FROM
(
  SELECT seg_airline, seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY seg_origin_code, seg_destination_code) cnt
    FROM t_n_segments
) q
 WHERE cnt = 
(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT seg_airline)
    FROM t_n_segments
)
```

Output:

```
| SEG_AIRLINE | SEG_ORIGIN_CODE | SEG_DESTINATION_CODE |
|-------------|-----------------|----------------------|
|          G9 |             BKK |                  OOL |
|          SG |             BKK |                  OOL |
|          6E |             BKK |                  OOL |
|          AK |             BKK |                  OOL |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25c86/3)** demo

Comment: Thank you. Its working fine. But it returns empty result when any of the airline dose not match with others.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you show that on sample data, preferably changing my sqlfiddle and posting a link to a new sqlfiddle after you click `Build Schema` here in comments. And in your requirements you said *common to **all** SEG_AIRLINE.*